# install problem with Broadcom driver--apparent disk label mismatch

Tags: wireless, drivers, system-installation, broadcom

I'm installing Ubuntu 13.10 on an Acer laptop which incorporates a Broadcom 4312 wifi adapter. When I was running off the live CD (from the 32 bit download) I was able to install the required `bmcwl-kernel` driver from the CD with the "additional drivers" app from the Software center. Everything worked fine.

Now I've gone through the install, and I cannot install the driver from "Additional Drivers (it simply hangs), nor have I been able to use apt-get in any form. Apt-get wants files from the installation CD labeled `ubuntu 13.10 saucy_salamander 386i` but the installation disk is labeled "Ubuntu 13.10i386", and apparently `apt-get` can't recognize it. I'm stymied. Does anyone know of a work-around?

device is `BCM 4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)`. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If it reports that it's not installed, that's fine, just continue:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and give us a report. The firmware is not on the DVD, so apt will likely not ask for it.